# jquery-ajax-json / success data parameter is null

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I try to send files via jQuery.ajax, and the posting is works nicely.
After the saving of file is done, I try to send back a JSON object of the database information like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");                
echo json_encode($DatabaseEntity);
die();
```

But client-side the ajax success callback's "data" parameter is null, instead of a JSON object.

jQuery.ajax is set up like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: /* url */,
    type: "POST",
    data: postingData, // it's a FormData object
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false, // it's because the FormData, if I set "multipart/form-data", then the data not sended
    processData: false,                                
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data); // => this is NULL, and I don't know why!
    }
});
```

Firefox FireBug shows the result: that's a well formatted JSON string

Have any ideas why "data" is null?

**UPDATE**

$DatabaseEntity contains something like that:

```
object(DatabaseEntity)#15 (9) {
   ["Label"]=>
   string(5) "somethinglabel"
   ["Description"]=>
   string(3) "somethingdesc"
   ["Link"]=>
   string(6) "somethinglink"
   ["FileID"]=>
   string(4) "1761"
   ["Order"]=>
   string(1) "1"
   ["Visible"]=>
   string(1) "1"
   ["ID"]=>
   string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: Because `$DatabaseEntity` is null from the serverside itself ..try to print it on the server side before the `json_encode` function and see whats in it

Comment: it's not null, it's an object

Comment: $DatabaseEntity is array ? can you specify $DatabaseEntity

Comment: I'm updating the question with the $DatabaseEntity spec. I hope it's useful..

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_encode("Values"=>$DatabaseEntity);

alert(data.Values);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning just one string, use the .d attribute

```
 alert(data.d)
```

Comment: i'm returning an object, but data is null so data.d also null